# Angular MDB pass the data from modal component to the parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, ms-access

I have a CRUD application and when I upload file to the POST api's endopint, it doesn't show on page untill I refresh. The same went for delete.

On delete I managed it to work by subscribing to the onClose event on modal/popconfirm.
The logic now should be the same, but problem is that, I don't know how to also "move" some other code like converting the file to base64. I know my description with words is not the best, but I will walk you through the working example (onDelete) and then show the code with not working problem when adding new file.

**Working exmaple:**
So here I subscribe to onClose and then with removeFile remove the file, which has the right ID. This happens in PARENT component, in which I then display the data. this.getData() is function where I call data with get request again AFTER the file is deleted, so it gets removed from front-end without refreshing the page.

```
openPopconfirm(event: Event, data: any) {
const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
this.popconfirmRef = this.popconfirmService.open(
  PopconfirmDeleteComponent,
  target,
  { position: 'bottom-left', data: { injectedData: data } }
);

this.popconfirmRef.onClose.subscribe(() => {
    this.apiService.removeFile(data.IdMultimedia).subscribe(() => {
      this.getData();
    });
});
```

}

In the popconfirm (modal) component then I just call this.popconfirmRef.close(), to close the popup.

**Example, which I can't get working:** The part which is commented has the right structure, but I don't know the right logic, so everything needs to happen inside this.modalRef.onClose.subscribe()

```
  openModalImage() {
this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(UploadImageComponent);
/*   this.modalRef.onClose.subscribe(() => {
    this.apiService.uploadFiles(formData).subscribe(() => {
      this.getData();
    });
});  */
}
```

*(By the way, code works fine, but i just need to refresh the page when I upload file to see changes)*
So for now, in the child component I do this:

```
 // Transform file to base64
 convertFile(file: File): Observable<string> {
const result = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
reader.onload = (event: any) =>
  result.next(btoa(event.target.result.toString()));
return result;
}

// Transform file when i select it via input field
   onFileSelected(event: any) {
     this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    this.convertFile(this.selectedFile).subscribe((base64) => {
      this.base64Output = base64;
    });
    this.fileOnHold = true;
  }

// On click upload function
onUpload() {
this.data = {
  fileName: this.selectedFile.name,
  nadomestnoBesedilo: this.nadomestnoBesedilo,
};

const formData: any = {
  IdProfilDelodajalca: this.IdProfilDelodajalca,
  Tip: 2,
  VsebinaBin: this.base64Output,
  VsebinaTekst: this.nadomestnoBesedilo,
};

this.apiService.uploadFiles(formData).subscribe(() => {});   

this.modalRef.close(true);
}
```

If you need any additional code as HTML feel free to comment. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This 2 line of code might need to be modify

From:

```
this.apiService.uploadFiles(formData).subscribe(() => {});               
this.modalRef.close(true);
```

To:

```
this.apiService.uploadFiles(formData).subscribe(() => {
    /* Something here*/        
    this.modalRef.close(true);
});
```

By your code, The modal won't wait until the upload process finished. The modal will rushed close.

Comment: yes, but that is what I am asking, what to put above modalRef.close in regards of logic inside the modal component

Comment: Can I have your HTML code?